# Django and the limits of SQLite

Tags: django, sqlite

I am building a small web app with django with the SQLite database and I am concerned about scaling issues. I don't expect too many users (less than 1000) and therefore not too many requests to read from the database.

However, an additional script, running separately from the app, downloads price data, and appends a new row to the database every second (timestamp, price1, price2, price3). Thus, the database will grow with approximately 86400 rows every day (432000 per week).

Given this setup and the relatively large numbers of rows that are added each day, is the SQLite database a suitable choice? Will it work when the number of rows goes into millions? Or is it the number of users/requests the limiting factor and not the number of rows?

Comment: Why do you need to use sqlite anyway? Why not just install postgres or mysql and have done with it?

Comment: Do you *really* need prices every second? Do you *really* need to keep last year's prices? Do you know [what the SQLite developers have to say](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) about when to use SQLite?

Comment: Daniel, I am using SQLite because I am a relative newcomer to Django and all tutorials are with this db so this is why I opted for it. If I need to I will look to other databases, but this is why I asked this question.

Comment: Mike, I do need prices every second, but I don't need to keep history longer than a month. Do you mean to suggest that I can "reset" just the price table every month?

Comment: @gpanterov: Write names of people you address like this: `@gpanterov`; the `@` form notifies us that someone is replying. Otherwise, we might never know.

Comment: @gpanterov: If your application allows it, and you delete unneeded rows from "prices", it shouldn't grow to more than about 2 million rows, right? SQLite can cope easily with 2 million rows; I'm not sure about constant writes though.